# Python - random card

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program in python in which the computer displays a random card when the user presses enter. The same card can not be printed twice. My code so far is:

```
from random import *

used = []

number = randint(1,13)
if number == 11:
    number = 'Jack'
elif number == 12:
    number  = 'Queen'
elif number == 13:
    number = 'King'

suit = randint(1,4)
if suit == 1:
    suit = 'Hearts'
elif suit == 2:
   suit = 'Spades'
elif suit == 3:
    suit = 'Diamonds'
elif suit == 4:
    suit = 'Clubs'

end = False

while end == False :
    get = raw_input('Press enter to get a card')
    if get == 'end':
        end == True
        continue
    card = number , suit
    for i in (used):
        if card == i:
            continue
        used.append(card)
    print card
```

So far it only outputs the same card every time the user presses enter and the program does not end when the user types 'end'. Can anybody find the mistakes?

Comment: Well, you're only generating the card once.

Comment: What happens when the user presses "Enter" for the 53rd time

Comment: It would be better to generate a deck, shuffle it using `random.shuffle` and iterate as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in the while loop you assign

```
card = number, suit
```

But `number` and `suit` were picked once before you enter the loop and therefore will never change. You need to reassign `number` and `suit` each time you loop.

Additionally, you are iterating over the cards in `used`, but initially there are no cards there, so that loop will never execute. And since the only place you add `card` to `used` is inside that `for` loop it will never add anything to `used`.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained why your code fails.  Here is a different approach.

Just generate a deck, shuffle it using `random.shuffle`, and iterate as needed:

```
import random

ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
deck = [rank, suit for rank in ranks for suit in suits]
random.shuffle(deck)

for card in deck:
    if raw_input('Press <enter> to get a card') == '': # enter pressed
        print card
    else:
        break
else: # for loop not broken.
    print 'all cards have been dealt'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the card choice into the while loop. As Morgan says. Like this :

```
from random import *

used = []


end = False

while end == False :

    number = randint(1,13)
    if number == 11:
        number = 'Jack'
    elif number == 12:
        number  = 'Queen'
    elif number == 13:
        number = 'King'

    suit = randint(1,4)
    if suit == 1:
        suit = 'Hearts'
    elif suit == 2:
       suit = 'Spades'
    elif suit == 3:
        suit = 'Diamonds'
    elif suit == 4:
        suit = 'Clubs'
    get = raw_input('Press enter to get a card')
    if get == 'end':
        end == True
        continue
    card = number , suit
    for i in (used):
        if card == i:
            continue
        used.append(card)
    print card
```

Comment: This still allows duplicates: `Press enter to get a card
(9, 'Clubs')
Press enter to get a card
(8, 'Clubs')
Press enter to get a card
(8, 'Clubs')
Press enter to get a card
('King', 'Clubs')`